# What is hierarchical prior in Bayesian statistics?

Tags: bayesian, multilevel-analysis

What are hierarchical priors?

How do they differ from the general concept of priors?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A regular Bayesian model has the form $p(\theta |y) \propto p(\theta)p(y|\theta)$. Essentially the posterior is proportional to the product of the likelihood and the prior. Hierarchical models put priors on the prior (called a hyperprior) $p(\theta |y) \propto p(y|\theta)p(\theta |\lambda)p(\lambda)$. We can do this as often as we want.

See Gelman's "[Bayesian Data Analysis](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/)" for a good explanation.

Answer (score 4):

When you have a hierarchical Bayesian model (also called multilevel model), you get priors for the priors and they are called hierarchical priors.

Consider for example:

$z = \beta_0+\beta_1{y}+\epsilon, \\ 
\epsilon \mathtt{\sim} N(0,σ)\\ 
\beta_0\mathtt{\sim} N(\alpha_0,σ_0),
\beta_1\mathtt{\sim} N(\alpha_1,σ_1),
\beta_2\mathtt{\sim} N(\alpha_2,σ_2)\\

\alpha_0\mathtt{\sim} inverse-\gamma(\alpha_{01},\theta_0)\\
$

In this case, you can say that, $inverse$-$\gamma$ is a hyperprior.

EDIT:
[This](http://www.terry.uga.edu/~rgrover/chapter_20.pdf) was very useful to me when I learned about Hierarchical Bayesian Modeling.  For an in depth explanation  and detail, you may refer to Gelman's [Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052168689X).

Comment: you get priors for the *parameters* of the priors

Comment: Why do you need to parametrize the parameters?